# How do I link a .dll to my project in Visual Studio C++ 2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dll, linker

I've been trying to learn about using .dlls using MSDN articles. This one in particular

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682507 (creating a simple dll and the run-time and load-time examples)

However I'm not sure how to link the "simple dll" in the first link to either of the other projects. I have read about adding a reference to the project, however whenever I try to add a reference to the project, nothing shows up.

(With project selected,

- Project -> References -> Common Properties -> Framework and Reference -> Add New Reference -> "No Items Found"

I have added both the .lib and .dll files as part of my project, but that didn't seem to fix the problem. I have also attempted to add the .lib file under

- Project -> References -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies

I'm not sure if I need to specify a path in that location. (I just tacked on myPuts.lib at the end) That said, I have not had much success linking the dll to either project.

I'm not sure if this will help much, but on the Run-Time Linking example, I have noticed that

```
if (NULL != ProcAdd)
{
    fRunTimeLinkSucess = TRUE;
    (ProcAdd) (L"Message sent to the DLL function\n");
}
```

does not trigger, but the debugger did enter the outer if-statement.

If anyone has any advice on how to get this working, or if they an alternative link on how to link a .dll to a project I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Did you get any compilation or link errors for Load-Time Dynamic Linking?

For Run-Time Linking, could you please check and share the return value from LoadLibrary() API call?

Comment: Pretty unclear what *actually* goes wrong.  Get ahead by putting *both* projects in the same solution so that the first bullet gives you something to select and the DLL will be present in the same directory as the EXE so that your test program can find it and load it.

Comment: I do get link errors for Load-Time Linking. I'm not sure what you mean by return value on the LoadLibrary call. It does not return a NULL value, so it enters the first if statement, but the function address does not appear to be valid, so it skips the second if statement and LinkSuccess is never set to TRUE.